I want to inherit the event view to my customer model in odoo but this error was appear how can i solve it?
I want to inherited event view to my customer model in ODOO but this error was appear the error is:
 File "/home/abdalrahman/odoo_apps/odoo.15/15/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 748, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate)
  File "/home/abdalrahman/odoo_apps/odoo.15/15/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 797, in convert_xml_import
    relaxng.assert_(doc)
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 3633, in lxml.etree._Validator.assert_
Exception

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/abdalrahman/odoo_apps/odoo.15/15/odoo/http.py", line 658, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/home/abdalrahman/odoo_apps/odoo.15/15/odoo/http.py", line 301, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
AssertionError: Element odoo has extra content: data, line 4

My xml file is:
<odoo>
  <data>
    <record id="view_event_form" model="ir.ui.view">
      <field name="name">event.event.form</field>
      <field name="model">event.event</field>
      <field name="inherit_id" ref="event.view_event_form"/>
      <field name="arch" type="xml"></field>
    </record>
  </data>
</odoo>


I believe that the arch XML should have content added, such as a new field or something similar. the code is correct but not complete

do you know what is the complete?

`
`
Depending on your need, you may want to add a new field, so the idea is you can’t have empty arch tags

How can he give you anything, you have to make the modifications. SO is not a platform to let others do their own work.

@MuhammadYusuf you can write down your comments as answer, because it is correct. The arch field is empty and odoo is expecting xml code there.
